# Do I have to verify all creators every time after creating an nft?

Tags: metaplex-js, nfts, verify

From the metaplex js test. After creating an NFT I need to verify all creator as such

```
metaplex.nfts().verifyCreator({ mintAddress: nft.address, creator });
```

Does it need to be done after every creation?
Can I create NFT and verify all creators in the same transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using metaplex to create your NFT (`metaplex.nfts().create()`) then you can pass in the `creators` option with the `authority` field set as a `Signer` object (for each creator). This will set and verify each creator.

So your options would look something like:

```
{
  uri: 'https://',
  name: 'My NFT',
  sellerFeeBasisPoints: 500,
  creators: [{
    address: creator.publicKey,
    authority: creator,
    share: 50,
  }, {
    address: creator2.publicKey,
    authority: creator2,
    share: 50,
  }]
}
```

Docs: https://metaplex-foundation.github.io/js/types/js.CreateNftInput.html

Comment: I also realized  that the privateKey of the second creator, which I don't have, is needed as well. Perhaps is it better to let the second creator do the verification by themselves?

Comment: @StevenBarragán yes, definitely need the priv key to verify